# Python. ООП. Переопределение метода класса в зависимости от условия

Tags: python, ооп, классы

Не могу разобраться с переопределением в зависимости от условий.
Нужно чтобы метод describe переопределялся в зависимости от bool значения, которое передавалось бы в аргументах.
P.S. С возвратом подсказали, но функция не хочет принимать bool значение

```py
class Bird:
    def __init__(self, name, size):
        self.name = name
        self.size = size
        self.full = False

    def describe(self, full=False):
        return f'Размер птицы {self.name} — {self.size}.'


class Parrot(Bird):
    def __init__(self, name, size, color):
        super().__init__(name, size)
        self.color = color

    def describe(self, full=True):
        if full == True:
            return f'Попугай -----'
        else:
            super().describe()


kesha = Parrot('Ара', 'средний', 'красный')

print(kesha.describe())
print(kesha.describe(True))
```

Comment: `return super().describe()`

Comment: Кроме уже подсказанного выше, `kesha.describe()` выдаёт такой же результат как `kesha.describe(True)`, потому что у вас дефолтный аргумент тоже `True`. Если хотите, чтобы вывод различался - передавайте в функцию `False`, либо опишите дефолтный аргумент `full=False`. Тогда эти два вызова будут иметь разный результат.